# Tree structure with values for internal nodes, arguments to __init__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, oop, recursion

Below class represents a tree structure  with internal node values. A fibonacci recursive function is used to make a `fib_tree`. I haven't come across the return call to class below in `fib_tree`. The notation `Tree (left.entry + right.entry, left, right)` has left me confused. In OOP, I am familiar with `obj_inst.att`, `obj_inst.method()`, `properties`, `self`, `__init__` etc.

Here `left.entry + right.entry` - left, right and entry are attributes of the object instance itself, then what does `attribute.attribute` mean?. What exactly is being passed here to `__init__`? Is this a popular technique, does it have a name that I can research on?

```
class Tree (object):
    def __init__(self, entry , left = None, right = None):
        self.entry = entry
        self.right = right
        self.left = left

    def __repr__(self):
        args = repr(self.entry)
        if self.left or self.right:
            args += ' ,  {0}, {1}'.format (repr(self.left), repr(self.right))
        return 'Tree ({0})'. format (args)


def fib_tree (n):

    if n == 1:
        return Tree (0)
    if n == 2:
        return Tree (1)
    left = fib_tree (n-2)
    right = fib_tree (n-1)
    return Tree (left.entry + right.entry, left, right)

fib_tree (4)
#Tree (2 ,  Tree (1), Tree (1 ,  Tree (0), Tree (1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tree (left.entry + right.entry, left, right)
```

This says "make a new instance of the Tree class, with a number, and two instances of Tree." (in this case... type checking not being much of a thing in Python).

Note that left and right aren't attributes, they are instances of Tree, created in the two lines above the return in fib_tree().

Comment: Oh! I totally missed that local scope in `fib_tree`. Couldn't get my mind out of the class. Thanks.